ASP.NET action file download zip folder not downloading after few files
I have an ASP.NET MVC project written in C#, where I create some PDF files and add them to a zip folder to download them.
The created PDF files are always the same, just other small texts on it.
Strange thing is, it works for some number of files. And I can't figure out why it won't for more than X files. If there are more than 3 or 4 PDFs, it won't download them anymore.
Size is not an issue, if I zip a larger file, it works. So it seems that it has something to do with multiple files. Usually the files are 200-300kb each in size.
This is the code, I also tried it with SharpZipLib, but I have the same issue.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadCsv(HttpPostedFileBase InputCsvFile)
{
    // ...OTHER CODE...

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var pdf in items)
        {
            var fileName = pdf.PdfName;
            var entry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName);

            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(pdf.Pdf))
            {
                fileStream.WriteTo(entryStream);
                fileStream.Close();
                entryStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return File(memoryStream, "application/zip", zipFolderName);
}

I tried it with larger request size in the web.config, but like I said, bigger zip files can be downloaded if the files inside are not multiple.
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="52428800" />

<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>

The PDF itself shouldn't be an issue too, because they are created correctly.
EDIT:
I tried the code in another similar project and it works.
I also tried saving the ZIP file directly in the same function, this works too. The ZIP file has no errors, files are inside and working.
So its just not downloading the file if it has more than X files inside.
Example:
2 PDFs zipped with 4mb total size works,
6 PDFs zipped with 2mb total size doesn't work

Assuming pdf.Pdf is a byte array, why are you not writing directly? i.e. entryStream.Write(pdf.Pdf, 0, pdf.Pdf.Length) ? What error message do you get? Is the problem in the zip-archive creation or downloading? It might be useful to test these part separately to help identify the problems.

Changed that, thanks.
I don't get any errors. Everything looks like its working fine, its just doesnt download the file.

Have you done any debugging? Have you tried catching any exceptions? Do you reach the return statement? Are you sure you are not just getting a timeout?

Ive added the webconfig part in my post.
the code reaches the return statement, it doesnt trigger any exceptions.
thats why i dont understand this thing... it looks like its working, it works for fewer files... the size limit standard as i know of should be 4mb, which i dont think is even reached...

i have done a few other tests to see what could be the problem:

Code works in another app.
Creating the ZIP File locally works, the ZIP File has no errors and the files inside are working.

